# PHP uploading and downloading files

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

I'm facing a dilemma on how to implement file upload and download in a PHP website.

I have these criteria:

1. Performance - does not give performance issues to the website
2. File size - around 2GB and up.
3. Authorization - I want to be able to change who can access the files in PHP. Allow multiple users to gain access to a single file.
4. User friendly - no additional tools to use.

So here are the methods I'm currently looking at and how I assess them based on my criteria:

Database BLOB

1. Writing the file data into the output stream will take time and blocks other requests (is this correct?)
2. I read somewhere that there's a size limit for BLOB.
3. OK - I can easily control who can download the files here.
4. OK - No additional tools, just the website.

FTP

1. OK - since it is designed to store files.
2. OK - file system is the limit.
3. I need to create another credentials for each user aside from the username and password for the website. I assume I have to move the file from one location to another to update authorization, but how if multiple users can access one file? Shared directory? It looks messy.
4. Need another tools/program for accesing their files, need to remember another username and password.

My questions:

1. Based on my assumptions, do you thimk I understand the methods correctly?
2. If my assumptions are wrong, is there a way I can do this functionality while meeting my criteria?

PS Please excuse my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the file system to store the files and store the path to the given file (+ permissions, if needed) in addition in a database.

The upload folder isn't accessible from the public and an wrapper script serves the content to the user.

1. Performance shouldn't be a problem as you just move/copy the uploaded file to a dedicated data directory.
2. File size isn't a problem (as long, as you have enough disk space)
3. The wrapper script handles permissions and serves files to the users
4. It's as friendly, as you design your ui

Comment: Thanks! I was about to add that as my option. How about the performance writing the file into the output stream?

Comment: Writing the file to the output shouldn't be the problem. The time to download the file is much higher, than writing it. If you don't use output buffering, the user could also download the file, even if it's not completly written

Comment: Will it block the next request?

Comment: Normaly you should have more than one worker process

Comment: I'm sorry, worker is kind of vague to me. I saw a pthread reference and stream_set_blocking. Are those what you're referring to or the PHP handles "workers" by default?

Comment: Thats part of the webserver - but in general, paralell requests don't block each other

Comment: I should mention, that you should maybe use `readfile` to serve the file to your users

Comment: So there are lot of ways to handle requests in parallel, knowing that is enough I guess. I've lot of readings to do. Thanks!

Comment: Oh! If you can point me to a tutorial/article with do's and don'ts when handling parallel requests, please I'll appreciate.

Comment: There's nothing special to do, if you don't run your own webserver. The point about using readfile is: if you first load a 2gb file in a string and then send it to the client, you have to keep 2gb in your memory, which might not be that clever..

Answer (score 2):

for me the usage of BLOB is not the best. I thought about BLOB to upload pictures in my own website, but the best way to upload file is to put them directly on ur server locally.